# How to limit the amount of error bars Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have over 1 thousand data points on a graph. I would like to plot some error bars every 100 or so points data points.

```
x = 1:1500:1100;
y = [1:1200];
err = ?
plot(x.y);
hold on;
errorbar(x,y,err);
```

What value do I need for 'err' so I would only get 10 error bars?

Comment: The very first line of this code is not doing what you think. The normal plot won't even work properly. Correct that before thinking about error bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386195/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-error-bars-matlab#comment103119993_58386195), your code is no proper MATLAB code. Nevertheless, I presume you have sufficient MATLAB understanding: Basically you need to set up separate `x` and `y` values for your `errorbar` as well as the actual errors `err`, which should be plotted. Then, you can use the proper [`errorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html#d117e363628) command.

Let's have a look at this small example:

```matlab
x = -5:0.1:5;
y = sin(x);

xErr = linspace(-5, 5, 11);       % Specify x locations for errorbar plot
yErr = sin(xErr);                 % The y values at these x locations
err = rand(1, 11);                % The actual errors, here: some random values

plot(x, y, 'r');                  % Plot
hold on;
errorbar(xErr, yErr, err, 'o');   % Actual errorbar plot at specific x locations
hold off;
```

You'll get an output like this:

[image: Output]

Disclaimer: I made this with Octave 5.1.0, but the syntax should be identical to MATLAB. If not, please report any errors.

Hope that helps!